# AVAudioSession in bluetooth switches strangely when interrupting playback of other apps

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, avaudiosession

I'm working on a VoIP app and i have handled the interruption of AVAudioSession in normal cases. **But i find that in bluetooth mode, when i start a call, the switching process from PlayBack to PlayAndRecord will not complete instantly. There will be a short play in low quality and loud volume during the switching time. After that, the playback will not resume even though the call is over.** This phenomenon appears randomly. Mostly at the beginning time, and then everything is OK. But after several times of calling, it happens again, which confuses me a lot.

I guessed at the beginning that it might be the problem of bluetooth category, so i added the options [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP]. But it did not work. Here's my code.

```swift
// setting of AVAudioSession
public static let voipCall: AudioSessionScenario = {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        return AudioSessionScenario("voip", category: .playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
    } else {
        return AudioSessionScenario("voip", category: .playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth])
    }
}()

// when user starts a call
AVAudioSession.queue.async {
    AVAudioSession.entry(AudioSessionScenario.voipCall)
}

// the entry method does nothing but set the setting of sharedInstance
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    try session.setCategory(category, mode: scenario.mode, options: scenario.options)
} else {
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().perform(NSSelectorFromString("setCategory:withOptions:error:"), with: category, with: scenario.options)
}
```

I expect that there is no strange play in the switching process and the playback will resume after the call. **It works well in normal cases including speaker and wired headset. Bluetooth devices like Bose QC30 or Airpods have the unstable problem.** Does anyone know the reason? Thx.